# Google Cloud Source Build Trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to set the CI/CD for a cloud function that I have built using Python run time which is in Beta. I am able to deploy the function manually but I am not able to do the cloud builder. I am getting 403 forbidden. I have set the cloud build service account with Function developer Role as well.

The build is getting triggered properly.

Below is the error.

Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[The caller does not have permission]
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I set the Project> Editor and works, but I have the same question as the other poster as well. It looks like its a lot of permission to provide.

Comment: the `Cloud Functions Developer` role might suffice... as explained in that answer.